# How to use or in checking presence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i need to check presence of a value in an array. It can be two values i need to check with an or case if it includes in the array. I think it will be confusing from my description you will understand after you see the code below.

```
if user.sheet_ids.include? params[:id].to_i || params[:sheet_id].to_i
  can :show, Project
end
```

It returns false even if sheet_id is present in the array of sheet_ids.

user.sheet_ids is an array and i need to check if any of the value includes in this array. The method i used is not seems to be working.

Is there any simple way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: "not seems to be working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: It is unclear from your description what the code is supposed to be doing. I understand that you want to check inclusion by `id` but only if that is defined, otherwise by `sheet_id`? Can you provide a [mre] including examples of desired inputs and outputs, both in normal cases as well as exceptional and boundary cases?

Comment: I am sorry for not describing the error i will update my question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag do i have to explain more i will surely do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
(user.sheet_ids & params.values_at(:id, :sheet_id).map(&:to_i)).any?
```

Answer (score -1):

`user.sheet_ids.include? params[:id].to_i || params[:sheet_id]` is executed in this way `user.sheet_ids.include?(params[:id].to_i || params[:sheet_id])`. The OR statement is executed and the result is what is passed as an argument to `user.sheet_ids.include?`

To check if either `params[:id].to_i` or `params[:sheet_id]` is included in the array `users.sheet_ids`, you need to do this;

```rb
if user.sheet_ids.include?(params[:id].to_i) || user.sheet_ids.include?(params[:sheet_id].to_i)
  can :show, Project
end
```

Comment: This is not working still returns false even if it is present.

Comment: @AmalTS: There are no examples in your question, no specification of what is supposed to happen, no test cases, no explanation of the rules for what you consider a correct result. The interpretation in this answer is a perfectly valid interpretation of your question. At the moment, there are three different interpretations of your question, which seems to clearly indicate that you need to add a specification, test cases, examples, and a [mre] to your question.

Comment: Are you trying to check if either `params[:id].to_i` or `params[:sheet_id]` is included the array `users.sheet_ids`? @AmalTS

Comment: Yes that's what exactly i am trying to do.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: @AmalTS I have modified the answer. Please check